# VBA - CopyPasteCode with Sendkeys

Tags: excel, sendkeys, vba

I'm using IDE in a excel workbook and trying to do the below code.

```
Sub cpypaste()    
    Range("E7").Select    
    SendKeys ("^c"), True    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))    
    Range("G7").Select        
    SendKeys ("^v"), True    
End Sub
```

Not that I do not know alternate ways of doing it, but just curious why this is not working. I've tried running this code with keyboard shortcut and cmdbutton as well.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code works for me,....

Comment: Any settings that I can modify in my excel application to make it work. Which excel version are you using?

Comment: xl'10... I just copied your code,pasted into a module and clicked run.

Comment: It doesn't on xl2007.. :(

Comment: How is it not working? Any errors?

Comment: It doesn't picks any data on clipboard and destination cell ( cell G7 ) has "marching ants " animation, as if I'm trying to copy from E7 rather G7.

Comment: Are you not trying to copy from E7? You would still get the "marching ants " because CutCopyMode hasn't been set to false. What do you have in E7?

Comment: i edit my comment- It doesn't picks any data on clipboard and destination cell ( cell G7 ) has "marching ants " animation, as if I'm trying to copy from G7 rather E7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sendKeys is fecal at best.  I assume you are starting the code from the code window,  and because of this, the commands are trying to refer to that window.  Excel needs to be activated to receive the commands.

```
Sub cpypaste()
AppActivate Application.Caption 'Activates the window.
Range("E7").Select

SendKeys String:="^c", Wait:=True

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))' this line I belive is not needed, with the wait as true.
Range("G7").Select
SendKeys String:="^v", Wait:=True

End Sub
```